# in action, return json("Partial view name") doesn't go to success of ajax

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have 2 function in my js file for 2 button.
when i try to:

```
 return Json("_ThanksForLogin");
```

it doesn't go to js file, doesn't go to success of ajax.
when click the button it just shows the string "_ThanksForLogin" in dialog box.
what should i do?

my function:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#loginBtn").click(function () {


        var user = getUser();

        // poor man's validation
        if (user.Username == null) {
            alert("please enter username.");
            return;
        }
        if (user.Password == null) {
            alert("please enter password.");
            return;
        }

        var json = $.toJSON(user);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Members/MemberLoginPartial/LoginUser',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: json,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success:
                     function (address) {

                         $("#resultMessage").load(address);
                         setTimeout(function () { $("#resultMessage").dialog("close") }, 1000);
                         location.href = "/Members/Members/Index";
                     },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                location.href = "/Members/Members/Index"
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I want to send address of "_ThanksForLogin" partial view by **return json()** in action  to this part:

```
 success:
           function (address) {

             $("#resultMessage").load(address);
             setTimeout(function () { $("#resultMessage").dialog("close") }, 1000);
             location.href = "/Members/Members/Index";
          },
```

and after it, the dialog close automatically and redirect to user profile.
thanks for helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json()` is supposed return a [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html), not html. What you need is

`return PartialView(_ThanksForLogin)`

which will return the `PartialView` named "_ThanksForLogin".

Comment: but i want to return it in dialog box that is in $.ajax.
4

Comment: What exactly is in your `_ThanksForLogin` page?

Comment: my problem was solved by using **"return PartialView("_ThanksForLogin", memberLogin);"** Thanks